# Links not active in firefox with bootstrap buttons

Tags: css, firefox, twitter-bootstrap

I ran into a strange issue while building my wordpress site. All links that are inside the bootstrap buttons are not active in firefox.

What could cause this?

Here's the html output:

```
<button class="btn pull-right" role="button">
<a href="http://domain.dev/?cat=4" name="View all News">
    All News
</a>
</button>
```

Here's the css:

```
.home #primary #home-more .btn {
background-image: url("../img/home-button-sprite-more.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
margin-right: 0px;
background-color: transparent;
padding: 13px 40px;
background-position: 20px 0px;
}
button.btn {
display: inline-block;
padding: 13px 24px; 
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-right: 10px;
font-size: 10px;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 1;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
cursor: pointer;
border: medium none;
border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
white-space: nowrap;
-moz-user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean 'not active' ?

Comment: @JoshC i mean not working, when you click on it, it doesn't take you to the page

Comment: Probably doesn't have anything to do with CSS then. It's the structure of the HTML. Perhaps the links changed, or the directories have been moved.. just some suggestions.

Comment: It is not valid to have an `<a>` inside a `<button>`, the [spec here](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-button-element) says there must be no interactive content descendant in a button element

Comment: @JoshC links are created dynamically, and the only difference between these and other working links is that these are inside the `button` tag with the above css... and only in firefox... weird

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Instead of,

```
<button class="btn pull-right" role="button">
<a href="http://domain.dev/?cat=4" name="View all News">
    All News
</a>
</button>
```

You have to use,

```
<a href="http://domain.dev/?cat=4" name="View all News">
  <button class="btn pull-right" role="button">
    All News
  </button>
</a>
```

Or,

```
<a href="http://domain.dev/?cat=4" title="View all News" class="btn pull-right">
    All News
</a>
```

Comment: Why does this happen? or what is the difference between the two codes?

Answer (score 1):

Try what @Devo has suggested else try this

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="http://domain.dev/?cat=4">All News</a>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<div class="btn pull-right" role="button">
  <a href="http://domain.dev/?cat=4" name="View all News">
      All News
  </a>
</div>
```

I think it should work

Comment: Use this:

<div class="btn pull-right" role="button">
<a href="http://domain.dev/?cat=4" name="View all News">
    All News
</a>
</div>